# ASP.Net MVC 3.0 Ajax.ActionLink Onbegin Function true the execute the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have  a Ajax Action link, which will call a action Method,

In my Ajax Option i have called a Validate function,

If this function returns true,

then only i would want this Action Execute, not sure how i can get this done?

My Ajax ActionLink

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Renew", "Edit", "Controller", new { id = "<#= ID #>" }, 
new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        OnBegin = "isValidDate",
                        OnSuccess = "DestroyRecreateAccordion",
                        UpdateTargetId = "accordion",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    }, new { @class = "standard button" })
```

How can I do this only if isValidDate returns true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**AjaxOptions** on Action Link

```
OnBegin="isValidDate"
```

JavaScript

```
   function isValidDate() {
       var date = $('#dateid').val()'
       //...check date....
       if(date is valid) return true;
       else return false;
    }
```

this worked

Comment: any idea on how to pass a parameter to this method ? I am trying this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024135/ajax-beginform-with-onbegin-prevent-action-to-be-called

Comment: I wanted to pass a single parameter that too from model to a javascript method, I found it Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024135/ajax-beginform-with-onbegin-prevent-action-to-be-called/10039566#10039566

Answer (score 2):

You need to return false on your OnBegin Method

```
OnBegin = "function(){ return isValidDate(); }", 


function isValidDate() {
    var date = $('#dateid').val()'
    ...check date....
    if(date is valid) return true;
    else return false;
}
```