# How to prevent submission of an ajax form until after kendo.confirm has been confirmed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have created an ajax form in asp.net mvc. I have created an OnBegin handler. In my OnBegin handler I call kendo.confirm. However, when this goes to handle the OnBegin event the form submission completes before an option is selected.

So I attempted to do this with a work around. Essentially using a button that calls the confirm and then submits the form from jQuery. This felt like a fairly hacky work around. And also when doing this I found there where some ModelState issues. The issues are resolved by using the normal Asp.Net method of submission.

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Form",new AjaxOptions {   
                                 HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                 OnSuccess = "SubmitSuccess", 
                                 OnFailure = "SubmitFailure",
                                 OnBegin="OnAjaxBegin"  }))
{
 ....
}
    function SubmitSuccess() {                           
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
    }

    function SubmitFailure() {            
        kendo.alert("....");
        kendo.ui.progress($("#Form"), false);
    }  

    function OnAjaxBegin() {
        kendo.confirm("Please confirm that a copy of the sample invoice has been donwloaded and saved").then(function ()                
        {                
            kendo.ui.progress($("#Form"), true)
            return true;
        }, function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
```

So in theory the form should only be submitted if confirmed. Instead the form is submitted and I hit my break point in my controller before any option is chosen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: So I have attempted to use return in my OnBegin handler and I still have the same result

```
OnBegin="return OnAjaxBegin()"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax.BeginForm with OnBegin prevent action to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024135/ajax-beginform-with-onbegin-prevent-action-to-be-called)

Comment: Did you try AjaxOptions.Confirm ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2